# Can't add prefix to XmlNode in XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces, xmldocument

I have been searching the whole day for a solution but nothing helped me so far.

I'm iterating through all the nodes in the XmlDocument like so:

```
    // iterate through xml
    soapEnvelopeXml.IterateThroughAllNodes(
    delegate (XmlNode node)
    {
        if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(node.Prefix))
            node.Prefix = "urn";
    });
```

Stepping through every single node, I noticed one node not having a NamespaceURI.

Is this why I can't add the prefix to the node? Also if that is the case, how can I change the NamespaceURI when it's a readonly property?

This is the namespace URI: `"urn:nl:portal:service:fileuploadnotification:env:1"`

Comment: You must add a namespace. Prefix will be added by itself.

Comment: Show us the original xml and the desired one.

Comment: The document must follow the schema for the URI.  If the schema doesn't have a prefix for the Node you can't just add the prefix.  Does the document meet the schema?  Test using a checker on the web.

Comment: I think I've come to a conclusion that the root node can not contain a NamespaceURI when you serialize it. Apparently only the child nodes will get the NamespaceURI assigned. I made a quick workaround by creating a class named RootXML with the Namespace added that has the object that needs the prefix for the URI. Might not be the best solution but it works for now.